# Giving nested VM, static internal IP or internal IP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-vpc

I have a nested VM inside a google cloud instance, and I want it to have internal IP, is there a possible way around. A little help will be appreciated. I also have a VPC, where I have reserved some static internal IPs, if first question is possible then is there a way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

GCP has a feature called alias IP range that will allow you to assign ranges of internal IP addresses as aliases to a virtual machine's (VM) network interfaces. This is useful if you have multiple services running on a VM and you want to assign each service a different IP address.You can use the documentation[1] to assign the ip address for your internal services/nested VM.

[1]https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/alias-ip

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the thing is for certain reasons I want to assign IP of same   subnet to the VM, but in IP alias we provide IP of different subnet right?